# ViewPager findViewById is null after screen rotation in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, screen-orientation, findviewbyid

I'm using a `viewPager` to display some forms. My problem is when i rotate the screen of the device and the `viewPager` is created again, it doesn't see the `viewPager` when he reaches the `findViewById`, it's always `null`. I have no idea how to handle it when rotation change.
I tried the `onConfigurationChange` but it doesn't work, I tried to save the `Id` of the pager and then retrieve it using that saved `id` but nothing too. So I'm quite blocked now.

```
pager = (CustomViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

In onViewCreated

Comment: Can you post your code? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

do this in `onActivityCreate` of the `fragment`

```
pager = (CustomViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```