# FindViewById is null after device rotation inside FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, findviewbyid, screen-rotation, android-runonuithread

I am trying to modify UI elements that are inside a `FragmentPagerAdapter` on a `ViewPager`. 
Everything goes well until I rotate the device. Then, `FindViewById` returns `null` and I can't modify the element.

When I rotate the device do I have to keep in mind some operation? 
`FragmentPagerAdapter` manages the Fragments when the activity re-creates? 
`runOnUIThread` has any implication on this? I am using something wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        //detect if it was recreating by rotation device
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            rotateEvent = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("rotateEvent");
        }


        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        ...
   }

   /**
     * On Received Status update on UI state
     * @param messageReceived: string received
     */
    public void updateReceivedStatus(final String messageReceived) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    int idElementToUpdate = getResources().getIdentifier(messageReceived, "id", getPackageName());

                    View element = findViewById(idElementToUpdate); // element is null after rotation

                    //Switch type send different message
                    if (element instanceof RadioGroup) {
                        //obtain id string of radiobutton
                        String radioButtonId = message.replace(":", "_");

                   ...
            }
        }
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. I've tried this but it seems not to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699006/viewpager-findviewbyid-is-null-after-screen-rotation-in-android